# How to speed up sending a large 2d Array to Google Sheet (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like some clarification/direction.  I have a script that transforms some data and here are a few screenshots of load time data. Each screenshot has the a breakdown of when it started, how long each section took to process, and the total amount of run time.

For 2000 rows of data.
[image: 2000 rows of data transformed]

For 5000 rows of data.
[image: 2000 rows of data transformed]

For 10000 rows of data.
[image: 10000 rows of data transformed]

For 19454 rows of data.
[image: 19454 rows of data transformed]

For 2000 rows of data, it took 21 seconds to transform it and 10 seconds to setValues() to the spreadsheet.
For 5000 rows of data, it took 22 seconds to transform it and 74 seconds to setValues() to the spreadsheet.
For 10000 rows of data, it took 20.5 seconds to transform it and 378 seconds to setValues() to the spreadsheet.
For 19454 rows of data, it took 18.5 seconds to transform it and 1780 seconds to setValues() to the spreadsheet.

Right now I am planning on breaking up the script to grab less data but is there a faster way to send the data to a spreadsheet other than setValues()?  I've looked into appendRow() but haven't been able to get it to work for a 2d Array.

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  benchmarks.

Comment: Try using th Sheets Advanced Service instead of the Spreadsheet (Basic) service. Anyway, the "benchmarking" data is uncomplete... What runtime is being used? It this done over the active spreadsheet ? Whay the fourth screenshot is different from the other three? Also add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask] I'm pretty sure that there are some Q/As suggesting to use the advanced service instead of the basic.

Comment: Like it or not,  it's the only exhaustive benchmark reference. Runtime is clearly rhino(given the last update).  The sample code suggests `.openById()` being used suggesting standalone script. The fourth figure shows "Inversion points"- At what point does  the process cost for sheets api is better than spreadsheet setValues. It is very important figure. In no way, is the benchmark incomplete.  I don't think V8 makes a difference(The author seems to think so too). If someone considers these factors to be significant, they should benchmark it and prove it to be significant and not vice versa

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for sharing that!  I made a few adjustments and included the openById() and now it runs in 55s.  Much better!  Thanks!

Comment: @OneInAMillion `openById()` means nothing. I said that to suggest that the experiments were run on a standalone script. It doesn't make a difference. Only thing  that would make a difference would be sheets api

Comment: @TheMaster That is strange...I wonder what made the difference then.  I didn't change much and am still using setValues();  After changing to openById(), it went from 4-5 minutes to setValues() to 30-40 seconds.

Comment: That's interesting.